# Jquery UI Tabs: Possible to have tab url as the browser url?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a tab structure which goes like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="tabnames">
        <li><a href="home.html" id="reportTabUrl">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">Create Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Manage Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="product.html">Manage Widget</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Permissions</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I want to know if there's a way in which the browser can reflect the URL of the active tab, i.e. `www.sampleurl.com/home.html` instead of `www.sampleurl.com` when I click on `<li><a href="home.html" id="reportTabUrl">Reports</a></li>`

Comment: Please add the full description for tabs I mean what do you want

Comment: When I click on any of the tabs, the browser URL should reflect the tab url, i.e. clicking the second tab should change the browser URL to : /about.html. Makes sense?

Comment: As far as I know `www.sampleurl.com/home.html` is not possible, but this is `www.sampleurl.com/#home`

Answer (score 0):

The idea of JQueryUI Tabs is to load pages using Ajax calls and improving user experience without reload.

`www.sampleurl.com` is an individual page, `www.sampleurl.com/home.html` is another one, `www.sampleurl.com/about.html` is another one, and so on. If you want that behaviour, your user will need to load webpage after webpage.

By default, JQueryUI Tabs load content using Ajax, so your desire behaviour is not compatible with this plugin.

Comment: ... and I believe you cannot update the browser URL without page reload?

Comment: I thought that you can't, but take a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: I did go through the MDN article sometime back which defines history manipulation. If you can put this as an answer (by editing your answer / adding a new one) I will be happy to accept the answer :)